# Encoding and decoding in PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, urldecode, encodeuricomponent

In my html file I am encoding an URL like this:

```
encodeURIComponent(url);
```

In my PHP file I use GET to grab the url and sanitize:

```
$url = filter_var(filter_var(($_GET['url']), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

I'm experiencing some trouble when adding other parameters to the URL. When I take out the javascript `encodeURIComponent` the whole thing starts working but I really would like to use `encodeURIComponent`, so I tried to `decode` the URL on PHP side:

```
$url = filter_var(filter_var((urldecode($_GET['url'])), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Doesn't work, I tried other things with no luck. I don't see how the above wouldn't work. What else can I try, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how often a technology that powers over half the web *doesn't work*.

Comment: This doesn't work `$url = filter_var(filter_var((urldecode($_GET['url'])), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` I think you are refering to PHP in general...:)

Comment: Please explain if downvoting, otherwise what is the point

Comment: @Youss What he's saying is that it's not that PHP doesn't work. It's that you don't understand how it's supposed to work.

Comment: You should be using `rawurldecode()`

Comment: @crush Where did I state that PHP doesn't work?

Comment: @bansi I tried that, doesn't work

Comment: @Youss, I didn't downvote. Just being facetious as **crush** noted.

Comment: @Youss Your question, primarily your title, is worded in a way that seems to indicate that you think PHP is not working as designed.

Comment: What are you getting at `$_GET['url']`

Comment: @bansi I get the complete url with no encoding characters, so just normal www.website.com

Comment: Try double encoding the url `encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(url));`

Comment: @bansi I can't seem to load my website...even my webhost company (https://www.yourhosting.nl/) is down...very strange, never happened before. I have to get back at you on this. Thanks anyway.